# Tracking cursor movement within a text with python and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to display the cursor position in the status bar of my app (line and column) like you see on most text editors.

I can display the cursor position but I am having trouble when it comes to updating it, I can update it when the text is modified using `self.text.bind'<<Modified>>', self.modified)` but I want it to update whenever the cursor is moved and not just when it is modified.

The other ways that I can think of moving the cursor are:

1. Clicking the mouse
2. Using the arrow keys
3. cut/paste

I thought I would be able to bind these also however the cursor position seems to update after the bind has been called an therefore always displays the previous position

I have created a small example to show my problem:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #Create the grid
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Create the text box
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
        self.text.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        #This sets the focus - I was hoping it would display the initial position
        self.text.focus_set()

        self.text.bind('<<Modified>>', self.modified) # Works as expected

        #All below bindings are 1 position behind
        self.text.bind("<Button 1>", self.updateStatus)
        self.text.bind("<Left>", self.updateStatus)
        self.text.bind("<Right>", self.updateStatus)
        self.text.bind("<Up>", self.updateStatus)
        self.text.bind("<Down>", self.updateStatus)

        #Add the status bar
        self.status_bar = tk.Label(self, text="", padx=5)
        self.status_bar.grid(row=1, sticky="se")

        #Call modified to display initial positon
        self.modified()
    
    def modified(self, event=False):
        #Update status
        self.updateStatus()
        
        #Reset modified
        self.text.edit_modified(False)

    def updateStatus(self, event=False):
        #Get cursor position
        cursor_position = self.text.index(tk.INSERT)
        
        #Update the status bar
        self.status_bar.configure(text=cursor_position)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: The simple way is to call `self.updateStatus()` periodically using `.after()`.

Comment: Why not replace all of those bindings to the arrow keys with `self.text.bind("<Key>", self.updateStatus)`. That will call it when any key is pressed. That includes copy/paste/cut/arrow keys/normal text input

Comment: @acw1668 what can slow down the computer when a code is continuously running in the background.

Comment: @TheLizzard It depends on how frequent and how much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #Create the grid
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Create the text box
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="none")
        self.text.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        #This sets the focus - I was hoping it would display the initial position
        self.text.focus_set()

        #All below bindings are 1 position behind
        self.text.bind("<Button 1>", self.updateStatus)
        self.text.bind("<Key>", self.updateStatus)

        #Add the status bar
        self.status_bar = tk.Label(self, text="", padx=5)
        self.status_bar.grid(row=1, sticky="se")

        #Call modified to display initial positon
        self.updateStatus()

    def updateStatus(self, event=None):
        # schedule an update after the key press is handled
        super().after(0, self._updateStatus)

    def _updateStatus(self):
        #Get cursor position
        cursor_position = self.text.index(tk.INSERT)
        
        #Update the status bar
        self.status_bar.configure(text=cursor_position)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I binds to **all** key presses and schedules an update just after the key event is handled by tkinter.

Comment: By the way I am going to use this in the text editor I am making :D

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly how I wanted with my example code, I'm not sure it will work if I use the edit menu to paste or insert but I could always manually call updateStatus() after this function. I'm not sure what super() does and I still need to learn *args and **kwargs. I will look this up as I don't understand what it is doing in your code

Comment: That's what I'm making just to learn Python and tkinter

Comment: `super().<function name>` is basically the replacement of `tk.Tk.<function name>`. `*args` is when you want the user to pass in multiple values. Note `args` becomes a tuple. `**kwargs` is when the user can pass in multiple key word arguments like: `function(foo=1, bar=2)`. Note `kwargs` becomes a dictionary. For the example `kwargs` will be `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}`. Gl with leaning python

Comment: Thanks for the info, very helpful